# Libgdx - textures

Tags: android, libgdx

If I create a texture of .PNG 1024 x 1024 and draw a circle in the middle that is 124 x 124, around it would be empty, does it use the same amount of RAM as if I would draw a circle 124 x 124 on a 124x124 space?

I could make all sprites in photoshop on a 1920 x 1080, and lay it out there already and then import all in game at a 0, 0 coordinate and all would lay out perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transparency has nothing to do with RAM usage - it depends on how big in decoded image it means that for picture `16x16` it will need 4 times more memory than for `8x8` no matter if it is transparent or not

Second thing is that by using pictures like this you will impact rendering performance because renderer will need to "iterate" over all pixels - also these transparent

Comment: I have a huge concern now, the following picture: http://prnt.sc/b0l2t3, is showing an object, the 4 shapes would be a pre-rendere falling object. I would paint this in photoshop and then with physics builder make collisions. But I am wasting like hell of a lot of RAM because my picture has like 3/4 of transparent (useless) pixels. I would it to be like the 2. example. So if I drew and make collision in like tiled2D would it use a lot less RAM? Because if not then I am lost to how people make a game like this. Because in Game Maker it's easy, but in libdx programming every single sprite is...