# LibGDX Texture quality for different devices

Tags: android, libgdx, textures, screen, resolution

A lot of different questions were asked around the question **"How to deal with Textures for different devices in Libgdx"**. I would like to summarize information here and ask what is not clear for me still.

Tips for the good quality of Textures:

1. Forget about the approach to build huge Textures with transparency. RAM will be destroyed on low devices. [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37050653/libgdx-textures)
2. Use [Viewport](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports). Aspect Ratio for Textures will look the same for each device. [explanation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Projection,-viewport,-&-camera)
3. Avoid raw textures. Apply the [TextureFilter](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.TextureFilter.html). [explanation](https://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1403)
4. Use [AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets). It allows you to load, dispose, make screen loading progress in the easiest way. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651323/libgdx-best-way-to-load-all-assets-in-the-game)
5. Use different resolutions for different devices. Use [ResolutionFileResolver](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/loaders/resolvers/ResolutionFileResolver.html). It allows Libgdx automatically to choose the most appropriate Texture for each device. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915535/libgdx-resolutionfileresolver-assetmanager-file-names)

*Note: feel free to add ideas to this list*

The question is about the last point. Android platform has a huge amount of different phones and tablets. I understand that it **doesn't make** sense to create each Texture for each Resolution.

1. How many resolutions to cover separately? I suppose to take 3 categories: for lower, middle and high devices.
2. If so - how to choose the most appropriate one for each category?
3. Are there any cases to use the same Texture somewhere? (small icons, HUD, etc)

Comment: I aim for 1920x1080 on Android. This way, it looks good o all high end devices while it still looks good on lower end devices.

Comment: @MrStahlfelge Thank you for the response. I would love to support old devices but your solution will lead to cut a lot of them.

Comment: Five year old devices run a resolution of 720x1280px. Textures designed for 1080x1920 are looking very good on such a resolution. Are you really expecting a lot of players from hardware more than five years old?

Comment: Ok, I found a site with statistics by resolutions. https://deviceatlas.com/blog/most-used-smartphone-screen-resolutions You are right that 1080x1920 is one of the most popular resolutions nowadays and most of the users will be fine. Also, I see a lot of  low resolutions and I'm going to support them as well. The question is how to choose the most appropriate resolutions for low devices or use different approach at all?